# How to get month name and year from datetime string

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a json containing field Month having string datetime-

```
{
 Month : "31-Jan-2022 12:00 AM (EST)"
 ....
 ....
}
```

How can I fetch Month Name and Year from this string using date functions in javascript?

I need output to be Jan-2022

Comment: That's an invalid date string so you cannot use new Date(..), you need a regular expression instead. Please look for existing answers before posting a question, there's a copious amount of existing questions about JS date parsing.

Comment: You can use format function from date-fns lib. It will look like this: format(new Date(your string here), 'mm-yyyy')

Comment: If the format is consistent (2 digits date, 3 letters month, 4 digits year), you can use `.substring(..)` something like this: `"31-Jan-2022 12:00 AM (EST)".substring(3, 11)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let str = "31-Jan-2022 12:00 AM (EST)"
let date = new Date(str)
const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
const year = date.getFullYear()
console.log(month,year);
```